# Access web server behind router, port forwarding not available

Tags: linux, ssh, router, port-forwarding, lamp

### The situation

I'm running a web server on a Linux development machine, and I'd like to give access to clients to view some sites without me having to upload them to an external hosting account.

### The problem

I don't have access to the router, and so can't set up port forwarding. I do however, have a hosting account (with SSH access) and even a VPS.

### The question

Is there something I could set up on my external hosting account or VPS that would handle web page requests by somehow pulling the data from my local server (behind the router) and serving it to the end user? I understand it's a bit convoluted, but performance doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2):

You could setup a SSH tunnel from your development machine out to your VPS which would allow you to give them access.  You'll need to setup remote port forwarding.  For OpenSSH client it would look something like this:

```
ssh -R 8080:localhost:80 user@server
```

Running that on the dev box should setup a tunnel from `server:8080` to your dev box port `80`.  You can then point your client to `http://server:8080`

Comment: This will only allow local connections to `server:8080` (i.e. only from `server` itself). To allow all hosts to connect to `server:8080`, enable the `GatewayPorts` option in the server's `sshd_config` and use the following command to connect to it from your dev box: `ssh -R *:8080:localhost:80 user@server`.